# undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this._registerEvents()')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

After i deleted my src folder in order to refactor this error occurred. I believe this is a caching issue? I tried following this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d) but no luck.

> "react": "16.4.1",
>
> "react-native": "0.56.1",
>
> "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
>
> "presets": ["react-native"]

`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './src/redux/store';


export default class App extends Component<Props> {
    state = {
        isLoadingComplete: false,
    };

    render() {
        return (
            
            <View>
                <Text>Hello??</Text>
                <Text>Hello??</Text>
                <Text>Hello??</Text>
                <Text>Hello??</Text>
                <Text>Hello??</Text>
                <Text>Hello??</Text>
                <Text>Hello??</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

`

Comment: What does your App.js file look like?

Comment: @Z_z_Z added in the post

Comment: You said you deleted your src folder, but here you are importing your store from "./src/redux/store". Try commenting out the import line and see if the error goes away

Comment: I already rewrite some of it. Commenting it out and still get the same error.

Comment: Try building a new project from scratch and copy/pasting the code you've already written. If it's a caching issue, it's often easier this way

Answer (score 5):

Open your terminal/CMD/shell and run these commands one after another

```
cd yourProjectDiectory  ----> navigate to your project directory

watchman watch-del-all

rm -rf node_modules/.cache

react-native start --resetCache
```

Answer (score 2):

close your server and run `npm start -- --reset-cache`
then reload the app

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after upgrade of React-native to 0.58.1.
None of the above answers worked for me. I tried to upgrade to 0.58.6, didn't help.

The problem was solved after upgrading to react-native 0.59.1.

Comment: I just upgraded to 0.59.9. No problem there, too.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21094#issuecomment-422245589

- add the `metro-react-native-babel-preset` package
- change `.babelrc` to (remove `react-native`)

  `{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
  }`
- `npm run start --reset-cache` or `react-native start -reset-cache`