# syntax 'nullishCoalescingOperator' isn't currently enabled

Tags: ios, react-native, syntax-error, react-native-ios

when I tried to build my app on ios-simulator it says :

bundling failed: SyntaxError: /Users/MyName/MyApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/Switch/Switch.js: Support for the experimental syntax `nullishCoalescingOperator` isn't currently enabled (167:52):

```
 165 |         {...props}
  166 |         {...platformProps}
> 167 |         accessibilityRole={props.accessibilityRole ?? 'button'}
      |                                                    ^
  168 |         onChange={this._handleChange}
  169 |         onResponderTerminationRequest={returnsFalse}
  170 |         onStartShouldSetResponder={returnsTrue}
```

`Add @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator (https://git.io/vb4Se) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.`

I did what it says, but it just didn't help...
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have the `Nullish Coalescing` operator right now, the proposal for `Nullish Coalescing` proposal is at stage-1 in TC39.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think it resolved by changing my .babelrc to

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

this change is caused by upgrading my react-native version

Comment: getting _this._registerevents is not a function thios error when I used it

Comment: @SamikshaJagtap ok that is an other problem, follow my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52713101/undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-this-registerevents/54021606#54021606

Comment: yes, i was able to fix with this just needed to fix some version dependency

Comment: I am still unable to resolve this issue. Also tried adding '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator' as a plugin.

Comment: @akshaygore did you try upgrading your react-native version ?

Comment: @MahgolFa My app was not using the correct .babelrc. Its working fine now. Thanks